# Was Grendel supernaturally protected from weapons?

Tags: beowulf

In a similar vein to ["Was the Doom of Mandos a curse or a prediction?"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/28849/4918), is the statement that Grendel can't be harmed by weapons a claim about some supernatural protection he's had, or a prediction about how he's going to be defeated?

Update: I mean in the ancient epic poem, not the recent film.

Comment: His skin was impenetrable.  " The sharpest and hardest iron/Could not scratch at his skin, for that sin-stained demon"

Comment: Are you referring to the poem or the recent film?

Comment: The epic poem. I completely forgot about the film.

Comment: And it runs in the family.  Hrunting cannot harm Grendel's mother,  but conveniently a *magic* sword beowulf finds in her cave can. He uses the same sword to decapitate G's body.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That certainly seems to be the implication. The [poem](http://www.heorot.dk/beowulf-rede-text.html) talks about Grendel having "*forsworen hæfde ecga gehwylcre.*", literally being impenetrable to (foreswearing) bladed weapons due to the "*on féonda geweald*", the administration (work) of fiends (demons).

Taken at face value, the writer is saying that Grendel can't be harmed by a bladed weapon because he's been cursed by demons.

> The protector of earls had no wish for any reason
>   the murderous guest to release alive,
>   nor his life-days to any people
>   counted as advantage. There many brandished
>   warriors of Beowulf, old heirlooms.
>   they wished prince-lord's life defend,
>   the legendary leader's, if they could do so:
>   they did not know that, when they joined the fray,
>   the bold-minded battle-men.
>   and on each side thought to hew,
>   to seal: the soul: **that the sin-scather
>
>   any on earth. of the choicest of irons.
>
>   of war-bills. none could not at all greet him
>
>   but he victory - weapons had forsworn.
>
>   every blade-edge. His life-severing was bound to
>
>   on that day in this life
>
>   be wretched. and the alien-spirit
>
>   into the administration of fiends would journey far away:** then he found, he who before many, miseries in his mind. on mankind atrocities committed

Obviously this doesn't prevent our hero from ripping Grendel's arm off and trying to beat him to death with the wet end.